# Mapping a function over a Collection

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, landsat-8, google-earth-api

I would like to calculate a MSI index for the each image of the collection and I developed below presented script. But, somehow it is not working and it says "midir.divade is not a function". Can anyone please assist me in improving the below script?

```
var image = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA")
    .filterBounds(point)
    .filterDate('2015-08-01', '2015-12-31');


var addMSI = function(image) {
  var nir = image.select("B5");
  var midir = image.select("B6");
  var msi = midir.divade(nir);
  return image.addBands(msi);
};

var withMSI = image.map(addMSI);

print(withMSI);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo:

`var msi = midir.divade(nir);` should be `var msi = midir.divide(nir);`